# How do you perform mysql contains with a url in python?

Tags: python, mysql, url, contains

I'm writing a script to query for articles within this week containing a certain url.  Im having trouble interpolating the the url, attempting to use the LIKE filter to check for a certain url.  I tried to interpolate as i did the published start and end week but it seems to get confused with the double interpolation.

to clarify, the script gets an error at `%{http://foo.com/bar}%` part of the query

```
start_week = today - datetime.timedelta(today.weekday())
end_week = start_week + datetime.timedelta(7)

cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE url LIKE '%{http://foo.com/bar}%'""", [start_week, end_week])
result = cursor.fetchall()
print len(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pythong doesn't like the brackets, it's get confused with nested interpolation. i'd suggest adding the %'s in a string and interpolating it within the query.

```
    bar = '%http://foo.com/bar%'
    cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE url LIKE %s""", [bar])
    result = cursor.fetchall()
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

What I had to do was add the percent in the string then interpolate in the sql query

Answer (score 0):

You have two WHERE operators in the query statement.

Change the second WHERE to AND in this line:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE published>=%s AND published<=%s WHERE url LIKE '%{$http://foo.com/bar}%'""", [start_week, end_week])
```

Should look like this:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE published>=%s AND published<=%s AND url LIKE '%{$http://foo.com/bar}%'""", [start_week, end_week])
```

Comment: i had switched it but it still doesn't like the interpolation i'm doing

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%{foo.com/bar}%' at line 1"), is the error i get when i get

Comment: yes i added your url encoder snippet from the urlib library.  I'm writing the script in python so i believe it has to do with the % getting confused with string interpolation